# Nested quantifiers translation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I translate the following statement in propositional logic by using nested quantifiers? " Not every student enrolled in programming class studies in computer science. "

We denote x: student; p(x): x enrolls in programming class; q(x): x studies in computer science

Thanks

Comment: not every is like the negation of for all, so it is there exists. 
so the statement is "there exists x" s.t. "p(x)" and not "q(x)" .. can you write it with quantifiers?

Comment: $\neg (\forall x: p(x)\implies q(x))$.

Comment: Start from "every student enrolled in programming class studies in computer science." It is quite simple and [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Types).